# adding a string to a variable in jquery adds it multiple times

Tags: jquery

when i store the value of something in a variable and then add a string to it so i can replace it it adds the string three times. i cannot figure out how to fix this.
here is the code.

```
var value = $("input[value='First USPS ___Mis.EasyPost']").parents('.shipping-option-item').find('.ui-button-text').html();
var newValue = value + '<br> <span style = "font-size:0.8em">Expected delivery</span>';
$("input[value='First USPS ___Mis.EasyPost']").parents('.shipping-option-item').find('.ui-button-text').html(newValue);
```

i also tried below and it also adds it three times

```
$("input[value='First USPS ___Mis.EasyPost']").parents('.shipping-option-item').find('.ui-button-text').append('<br> Expected Delivery');
```

here is the html snippet

```
<div class="shipping-option-item">
  <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="First USPS">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <div class="option-description">
          First USPS
       </div>
  </span>
  <div class="option-name ui-buttonset">
    <input id="shippingoption_1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" name="shippingoption" onclick="getDeliveryEstimation('Mis.EasyPost', 'USPS First')" value="First USPS ___Mis.EasyPost" data-shippingmethod="Mis.EasyPost" data-shippingmethodoption="USPS First">
    <label for="shippingoption_1" class="ui-button">
       <span class="ui-button-text">First USPS - $2.99</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="option-description" style="display: none;">
    First USPS
  </div>
</div>
```

here is what it looks like after the jquery code is added

```
<label for="shippingoption_3" class="ui-button">

<span class="ui-button-text">Express USPS - $24.25
     <br> <span style="font-size:0.8em">Expected delivery</span>
     <br> <span style="font-size:0.8em">Expected delivery</span>
     <br> <span style="font-size:0.8em">Expected delivery</span>
                            </label>
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML this is a guess, but `parents()` can return multiple elements. Try using `closest()` instead. If that doesn't help, please add the HTML to the question so a demonstration of the issue can be created

Comment: so swap parents with closest? sorry i cant provide the html i am only able to add html to the bottom of it so i am kind of hacking it in based on using the inspect method of a browser. when i copy what html is there into a jquery tester my code works perfectly fine.

Comment: added html snippet from inspect in browser of what i am applying jquery to

Comment: @bigs89 whats in `getDeliveryEstimation` function? and how do you bind change event on radio? ideally, radio button should have change event instead of click otherwise it will be executed everytime it's been clicked regardless of checked status.

Comment: @Pirate thats why i didnt want to include the html as stated i dont access to all the code it calls a lot of stuff i dont have access to. i only can look at the inspect method in a browser and then add jsquery to the bottom of the page. also there is no buttons changing anything on hte page so idk what your refering too. when the page loads it loads a box of selectable options for shipping that you then select and continue checkout

Comment: @bigs89 without being aware of the full functionality, it's hard to tell. When does the code you added triggers ? is it on `click` event or something? when should it happen?

Comment: @Pirate it just gets added to a div at the bottom of the page(it is the only access i have to alter the site) so i assume it is when the page loads up. im sorry i dont know much about jquery or html just using what little i do know along with my programming knowledge to try to figure some stuff out.

Comment: @bigs89 but when do you want to trigger? If I am not wrong, it should not append text on page load. It must happen when a radio selection changes or something else happens. If you just put it in `div`, it will be executed every time that piece of code gets executed. [Read this `on` event from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and try to modify your code to be run on let say `change` event of radio.

Comment: @Pirate so could it be adding it three times because there is 3 shipping-option-items being added as selections? i just did some testing as i switch between shipping options it adds the line more and more times. so how do i change it to add only when that specific shipping option loads?

Comment: @bigs89 may be, but as I said, it's hard to tell without knowing the full functionality. Sorry, I have no more ideas. You could try wrapping it in event handler and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @Pirate so after some research and testing and all the information you have provided it appears that the statement runs every time a shipping option is loaded or refreshed. idk if that gives you any indication of a way for me to prevent this from doing it so that this code runs once when the page itself loads and then doesnt run again

Comment: @bigs89 if it has to be run on page load and that too once only, what you could is wrap your code in `if` statement. Declare a `boolean` flag at the top of the page (or wherever so it only loads once in a lifetime of page) and set to `true`. After the code is executed, set flag to `false` so the condition will be false next time the shipment loads. This may not be ideal because it can cause unexpected behavior. I don't know how site works, so unfortunately there is nothing much I can do.

Comment: @Pirate thank you for all your help. it has made me closer solving this problem.